# Detect Left click and change it to Middle click o Ctrl+Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a personal website where you can listen music while reading the content. After `Firefox` released the `66` version with the "autoplay" blocked, I'm having a lot of problems with the audio.

By the default, the audio player it's stopped so the user has to started it (and comply with the new behaviour standard that browsers want) but I've discovered that when I click on the links and it opens in a new tab `target="_blank"`the audio stops playing and the canvas animation also.

But I've discovered that if I open the links with the `middle button` of the mouse or I use `Ctrl + Click` the tab opens without changing to it on the background and the audio and the animation still works and don't stop.

So, I've been trying to change the default behaviour of the `left click` to fire a `middle button` or `Ctrl + Click` when I click on a link but I can't make it work.

I want to detect a `left click` on the entire document and change the behaviour to `middle button`or `Ctrl + Click` (but maybe this is an ugly approach) or make a function and call it on the `<a>` tag with the `onclick=_the_function_`

At the moment, I can detect the button ([Reference](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#button)):

```
$(document).onclick(function(event) {
  if (event.which === 0) or (event.button === 0) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    # here I want to change the pressed button
  }
});
```

But I don't know in which variable I have to change the value of the pressed button. Or if this approach it's not the correct way.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom event that sets `event.button` and trigger that instead when the applicable links are clicked.

Something like:

```
$('a.someClass').click(function(e) {
  if (e.button !== 1) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation()
    console.log('Prevented left')
    var evt = jQuery.Event('click', {button: 1});
    $(this).trigger(evt);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Unfortunately, the event it's not triggered, it only shows the message on the console.

Comment: Thought that might happen. It will get triggered...can log it outside of the `if()` but it might be browser preventing it happening since it isn't initiated by user

Comment: Maybe it's the browser blocking it... I've to investigate more deeply what's happening to see if I can find other solution to this problem. Thank you for your help!